# getting background image to match size of center image

Tags: html, css

I am working on a background right now that requires I do some fancy work with CSS3. The project in question is located at the site http://www.cbs-scb2014.ca/. If you are to go to that site you will see that the background image is larger than the actual center image. I was hoping to have the black line up with the black and the green with the green without that extra black on the bottom and the staggered black along the sides. I have pasted the corresponding css below:

```
html {
    background-color:#017D85;
    background:url(images/CBS2014spalshborder.jpg);
    background-size:100% 697px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the position:

```
background-color: #017D85;
background: url(images/CBS2014spalshborder.jpg);
background-size: 100% 648px;
background-position: 0 40px;
```

Comment: Thank you my man. I will mark as answered. I have one more question. How do I get rid of the little space at the end. I actually switched it around so html has the background color and body has the background image.